# java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link freemarker/core/TemplateElement

Tags: java, freemarker, jboss-eap-6

My problem is that i have an ejb which internally uses freemarker tool to generate a HTML page, built and deployed to JBoss EAP 6.4.10. When i try to access this functionality (which generates HTML code using freemarker tool), jboss throwing below errors:

> java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link freemarker/core/TemplateElement
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/tree/TreeNode

I added freemarker jar in my jboss modules and it's module.xml looks like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.freemarker">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="freemarker-2.3.25.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it is found out that the error is due to missing dependency 'javax.api' in freemaker's module.xml file, after adding this dependency in module.xml as below the problem has resolved.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.freemarker">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="freemarker-2.3.25.jar"/>
</resources>

<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google App Engine has this same problem, that some classes that are mandatory in Java SE aren't present there. So try to use `org.freemarker:freemarker-gae` instead of plain `org.freemarker:freemarker`.

What kind of platform is that anyway, why's that class missing? Is it Google App Engine?

Update: Certainly JBoss EAP's class loader doesn't export the `javax.swing` package from some reason (see comments). While using freemarker-gae works that around, then you have to be careful to exclude the non-gae FreeMarker-s coming from elsewhere as transitive Maven (or Gradle, etc.) dependencies. So it would be more maintainable to fix the JBoss modules configuration instead. I saw some start JBoss EAP with `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=javax.swing`, though if Swing is available for other modules in the same JVM, then there must be a more elegant solution, such as adding something to `deployment-structure.xml`, or if you define your own JBoss modules then to its `module.xml`. Maybe you should check which standard module exports the swing packages ("javax.api"?), and try to declare that module as a dependency.

Comment: it's not Google App Engine, it's running on JBoss-EAP-6 and the missing class is javax.swing.tree.TreeNode.

Comment: Last time I have used JBoss EAP, it was running on standard Java. What's the different there? Is it maybe just that JBoss does its class loader magic and deliberately hides `javax.swing` (something you can most certainly configure)? Anyway, my answer still applies. `freemarker-gae` doesn't depend on `javax.swing.tree.TreeNode`.

Comment: I have other modules which use javax.swing and run on JBoss without any errors. may be you are right that its JBoss module loader's magic and is mostly configuration issue(but unresolved mystery yet.). 
Anyway, as you said, using `freemarker-gae` resolved the issue. Thank you very much for your help @ddekany

Comment: I would recommend figuring out the JBoss modules configuration though. See update.